# How to create query that groups Years

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT Count(tblpeople.PersonID) AS Total, 
     YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(tblmembership.MemberSince) AS YearsMember   
FROM tblmembership 
   INNER JOIN tblpeople ON tblmembership.PersonID = tblpeople.PersonID
WHERE 
      tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Back from VPM' 
  OR  tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Sent To VPM 2' 
  OR  tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Sent To VPM 1' 
  OR  tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Back from VPM' 
  OR  tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Renewal'
  OR  tblpeople.MemSTATUS = 'Active Member'
GROUP BY YearsMember 
HAVING YearsMember
ORDER BY YearsMember
```

It gets counts on years people have been a member.

```
What has me stumped is the boss wants it broken down by:
0 - 2, 
3 -5, 
6 - 10, 
11 - 20, 
>20
```

So counts for each. I can not figure out how to do this, though I'm sure there's a way!

I can just bring this into excel and manually group the counts, but wanted it done all in one shot.

Thanks

Comment: `HAVING YearsMember` what is that? what condition are you using? Your question is not clear? You mean you query not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use a case when expression: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

```
case when years between 0 and 2 then ... else ...
```

Comment: I have been trying, Just can't get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` instead of all those `OR` statements.  Then use a `CASE` statement to group your results:

```
SELECT Count(tblpeople.PersonID) AS Total, 
    CASE 
      WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(tblmembership.MemberSince) BETWEEN 0 AND 2 
      THEN '0-2' 
      WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(tblmembership.MemberSince) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 
      THEN '3-5', 
      ...
      WHEN YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(tblmembership.MemberSince) > 20 
      THEN '>20'
    END AS YearsMember 
FROM tblmembership 
    INNER JOIN tblpeople ON tblmembership.PersonID = tblpeople.PersonID
WHERE tblpeople.MemSTATUS IN ( 'Back from VPM', 'Sent To VPM 2', 'Sent To VPM 1', 
                               'Back from VPM', 'Renewal', 'Active Member')
GROUP BY YearsMember 
ORDER BY YearsMember
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd963/4)

Comment: @user3663270 -- np, please accept the solution if it helped!